# Header fields showing in Firefox but not showing in Chrome

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom FormTab screen where I have three header fields in the form section, and several other fields (from the same DAC) in the tab section.

It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome, the third and last header field gets cut off.  Nothing I've tried in the layout will get this field to show.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: If standard screens don't have this problem,  I wonder if it might be handling of height/width settings or autosize by the different browsers.

Comment: Usually, I've seen this because the height of the top / form section is set to a specific number of pixels.  When I change that to "100%", it normally fixes the problem.  In this case it doesn't...

Comment: I usually set width to 100%, but I set height to pixels.  I'm still learning a lot of the settings you can make, but I have had problems when not using autosize.  Do you see any difference if you (a) set height in pixels, (b) enable autosize with no other settings for height in the form directly or in autosize (i.e. minheight), and (c) enable autosize and set a minheight?  Do any of those have any impact on your issue?  Sure seems you should be able to copy settings from a standard screen and massage it taller or shorter if needed.

Comment: What are the browser zoom settings? Both are zoomed at 100% ?

Comment: Setting Height with Pixel works fine but might be unrelated. Give at least 8 pixels more than necessary to account for difference in rendering from different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the form section height to a specific number of pixels instead of "100%" (also setting the AllowCollapse="false", but this wasn't absolutely necessary), and this fixed the problem.

<px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="NewECO" Width="100%" **Height="100px"** AllowAutoHide="False" SyncPosition="True" TabIndex="1900" **AllowCollapse="false"**>